# nginx listen on subnet or wildcard?

Tags: azure, ubuntu, elasticsearch, nginx

I am using an ElasticSearch Virtual Machine image in Azure (ARM style).

I want to be able to create a new VM from this image and have it join the cluster automatically.

We use Nginx as a proxy to provide SSL and security without X-pack.

The downside is I need to open the nginx config file and set the IP address in the listen directive to the IP of the machine on the virtual network e.g. 10.1.0.5, when it starts up, meaning adding nodes to the cluster is less automatic than I would like.

```
server {
    listen 10.1.0.5:9200 default ssl;

    #snip
}
```

Is there a way to parameterise it? E.g. `10.*.*.*`?

I cannot just put `listen 9200 default ssl` because ElasticSearch is already listening on localhost:9200.

Basically I want to use the value of `inet addr` when running `ifconfig`

This is Nginx running on Ubuntu.